# Artifactory SaaS - User Plugins - How to deploy?

Tags: groovy, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I've been through the docs several times and the best answer I can find is that all the .groovy files are loaded at initialization of the application, however, for the SaaS variant of Artifactory it says the user plugins are supported in the product matrix but there's absolutely no reference on how to get the user plugins installed and running.  Maybe I'm tired and missing it but I keep ending up at this page in the wiki with no answer.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-PluginsLibDirectory

I am an admin user for the application but I can't see where user plugins are managed from the API, CLI or UI.  Please point me in the right direction.  Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a support request. DevOps team will do it for you.

Comment: This is only correct for a dedicated customers and not for shared tenants